# Rows matched: 1 Changed: 0 Warnings: 0 Mysql update not happening

Tags: mysql, sql, dml

I am updating a table from mysql command line.. update is not happening..

The table description is as follows:

```
mysql> describe userdailycalorie;
+-------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field             | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id                | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| balanced_diet     | bit(1)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| calories_consumed | double   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| date              | datetime | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| user_id           | int(11)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.13 sec)
```

Corresponding table contents are as follows:

```
mysql> select * from userdailycalorie;
+----+---------------+-------------------+---------------------+---------+
| id | balanced_diet | calories_consumed | date                | user_id |
+----+---------------+-------------------+---------------------+---------+
| 16 |               |                 0 | 2018-02-02 00:00:00 |       3 |
+----+---------------+-------------------+---------------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Corresponding Update statement is as follows:

```
mysql> update userdailycalorie  set calories_consumed= 205.4  and balanced_diet =true WHERE user_id = 3;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Rows matched is 1 which indicates it picked the row.. update is not happening as changed : 0.. I am not sure why,... can anyone help me debug this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want update two field cant use `AND`, separate each field to be updated with coma `,`

```
update userdailycalorie  
set calories_consumed = 205.4  
  , balanced_diet = true 
WHERE user_id = 3;
```

Comment: Oh!.. It worked after removing And and adding comma..Thank you..
On the other hand, i wonder why sql dint give that as an issue.. i mean what did it consider it as?

Comment: My guess is try to do a boolean operation. But not sure why didnt give error.

Comment: There is no guessing required.  `set calories_consumed= 205.4  and balanced_diet =true` → `set calories_consumed = ((205.4) AND (0))` because `balanced_diet = true` is false, so the net effect of the query is `set calories_consumed = 0`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try below -

```
update userdailycalorie  
set calories_consumed= 205.4, balanced_diet =1
WHERE user_id = 3;
```

Comment: no change.. same output

mysql> update userdailycalorie
    -> set calories_consumed= 205.4  and balanced_diet =1
    -> WHERE user_id = 3;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0